# How does Captain Salazar know about the compass?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

When Jack Sparrow gives away his compass and releases the Silent Mary from Devil's Triangle, Captain Salazar immediately knows that Sparrow has given away the compass.

How does he know about Jack's compass and it's link to his curse?

Comment: It's a plot hole for which there could be multiple explanation. [Check here](https://moviepilot.com/p/jack-sparrow-s-compass-has-led-to-a-major-pirates-plot-hole/4282370)

Comment: @Rahul: There is one exception to this, that the article does not mention. What if the compass' curse simply brings out **whatever you fear most**? E.g. if Jack had bartered with the compass during DMC, then the compass would've set Davy Jones loose on Jack, as opposed to Salazar (since Jones was the bigger threat at that time). This would make for a fitting cursed object: It helps you find what you desire most, but if you stop chasing what you desire, it makes _whatever you fear most_ find you instead.

Comment: @Flater: You got a point. But when Jack bartered compass he wasn't aware that Salazar was looking for him or that dead has taken over the command of sea. How would then Salazar be his greatest fear ?

Comment: Perhaps Jack isn't aware of Salazar's status, but he was aware of the Trident as he and Billy Turner are responsible for trying to hide it underwater after it was used to control merpeople in junior novel, Trident of Poseidon. However it is Barbossa that leaves the journal to Carina...The only thing I think is safe to assume is that the history between these characters is still unraveling and mythos is building with it. Obviously this doesn't answer the question, but maybe also some magical objects work in tangent or have their own conscious, so Jack doesn't have know, but the compass does?

Comment: @Rahul: During the first PotC movie, Jack wasn't actively worried about Davy Jones either, but their deal had already been struck and Jack was aware that the deal would eventually expire. Jack simply doesn't worry about what's not in front of him. Salazar being stuck means that Jack has no reason to _currently_ fear him. Following my suggestion, the compass' curse chose to free Salazar because it knew that Salazar's main goal would be to get revenge on Jack. THe decision isn't based on _Jack's fear_ but rather _Salazar's thirst for getting revenge on Jack_. Jack only fears it if he knows it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not like Salazar and his crew are completely isolated there.  We know that occasionally other ships arrive there, and are then attacked by Salazar and his crew. And he always leaves a man alive to tell the tale (why he expects a single man to routinely survive the return journey, I don't know).  All he has to do before letting them go (or killing them) is to interrogate them to learn more about exactly how he got trapped in there and by whom.  We see him do this with Barbossa, even. Other pirates and sailors do seem to know about Jack to some degree.  Enough years, enough pirates squealing to save their lives, and bingo bango, you piece together names, mysteriously prominent compasses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that Salazar could be aware of the compass long before he went to the  Devil's Triangle. Salazar also sees the compass in Sparrow's hand while his ship is being wrecked. That explains why Salazar immediately knew that Sparrow has given away the compass that led to the end of his curse.

Comment: Just to add: IMO DMTNT seems like it sets up things for the final film(s). During that flashback sequences we witness Salazar battling it out with several pirates, including Jack's former Captain, Captain Morgan aboard the The Wicked Wench, which is eventually ressurected and rechristend, The Black Pearl. The film didn't even explain why Salzar escaping in particular would be the thing he was fearing most---it just seems like the audience is missing some fundemental piece of information and/or that Salazar/Compass/Breaking Trident is only catalyst to what Jack really fears. Esculation of fears

Comment: No, seeing Jack swinging something from a string after the bootleg turn does **not** explain why or how Salazar knew that Sparrow had given it away or even that it was a compass, nor would it let him know that the curse was broken.